# I made a scramble game command but capital letters crash the bot for some reason

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made a little command that makes it so if someone, for example, inputs `&scramble apple`, bot would send "The word is: paple". It works as intended but the current issue is that if someone sends "Apple" instead of "apple", the bot just crashes saying that it can't get the author of undefined

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'scramble',
    execute(message, args) {
        const Discord = require('discord.js')
        let givenword = args.slice(0).join(" ");
        
        function scramble(givenword) {
            var word = givenword.split("")
            n = word.length

            for(var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
                var tmp = word[i];
                word[i] = word[j]
                word[j] = tmp;
            }
            return word.join("")
        }
       scrambledword = scramble(givenword)

       const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       .setTitle('Scramble time!')
       .setColor("RANDOM")
       .setDescription("The word is: " + scrambledword)
       .setFooter('You have 30 seconds to try and guess it, the first person to answer correctly ')
         message.channel.send({embed});
         message.delete()

      
       const filter = m => m.content.includes(givenword);
       const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 30000 });
       
       collector.on('collect', m => {
            console.log(`Collected ${m.content}`);
       });
       
       collector.on('end', collected => {
           message.channel.send(`${collected.first().author} got the correct answer first! The answer was ${givenword}`);
           console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
       });
        


   }
}
```

Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 errors there:

1. You need to handle case mis-match. I would suggest, before scrambling the word, making it lowercase and also making responses lower case before evaluating them.

```
var word= givenword.toLowercase().split("")
```

```
const filter = m => m.content.toLowercase().includes(give word)
```

2. You need to handle the case where no correct guesses are made. `collected.first()` is undefined because there are no winners. I would recommend checking for winners before printing the winner.

```
if (collected.length <= 0) {
// send no winner message
} else {
// send the winner message
}
```